# Make the if statement shorter

Tags: python, optimization, code-formatting

I have following code:

```
if sys.argv[2].isdigit() and sys.argv[3].isdigit() and sys.argv[2] >='3' and sys.argv[3] >='3':
    print 'works'
else:
    sys.exit()
```

it's works, but I try to find a way how to make "if sys.argv[2].isdigit() and sys.argv[3].isdigit() and sys.argv[2] >='3' and sys.argv[3] >='3':" shorter and more beautiful. Is there any way to reach this? Thx!

Comment: What if the `arg`s contain multi-digit strings? Can you first clarify what the problem is you want to solve?

Comment: `"12" >= '3'` is `False`, for example.  Is this what you intend?  If not, casting the values to `int`s (and catching any errors) is probably nicer than doing string comparisons.

Comment: Try using the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module instead.

Comment: @Iguananaut: although that is in general a good idea, I think here it is rather overkill if we only want to check two numbers. Since parsing it requires writing extra logic as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you give me an example?

Comment: `isdigit()` will only work for a single-digit input.  Soon as I input `10` it will break.  Also they need to cast to `int()` which will required some `try/except` anyways.  Simpler to just use argparse and `type=int`.  Also, the additional logic of checking `>3` can either be handle in argparse (more complicated) or after `parse_args()` .

Comment: @KarlsD: `"123".isdigit()`  is `True`.

Comment: @Iguananaut: no, `"123"` is `True` as well.

Comment: Ah, true, I missed that.  Regardless they still need to convert to an int if they want to do integer comparison.  I think using `argparse` is simpler.

Comment: @Iguananaut argparse is to overkill here, I just want to check only two numbers.

Answer (score 4):

This is a nice, expandable condition to replace yours:

```
all(map(lambda x: x.isdigit() and int(x) > 3, sys.argv[2:4]))
```

This will be true if all elements of `sys.argv[2:4]` are numbers greater than 3. This might also be overkill for checking two numbers, but this is much more readable than checking everything separately and it should be abundantly clear to anyone who reads this what you are trying to do.